# Error 80020101 when adding ground overlays

Tags: delphi, gmlib

I'm using gmlib 1.1 with Delphi Xe2, Os is XP sp3, internet explorer is version 8.
My problem is that I cannot programmatically add ground overlays at runtime, while all is ok if I do this at design time: on program starup the overlays are loaded and correctly shown.
In specific, if I add any image at runtime I get an error 80020101.
Doing some investigation, I peeked into the source code and I had to modify the TGMGroundOverlay. Add function like this, since it seems that I get the error when the overlay get updated while properties (latitude, longitude etc) are assigned:

```
function TGMGroundOverlay.Add(Url: string; SWLat, SWLng, NELat,
  NELng: Real): TGroundOverlay;
begin
  Result := TGroundOverlay(inherited Add);
  result.FVisible:=false;//<---added this line
  Result.Url := Url;
  Result.Bounds.SW.Lat := SWLat;
  Result.Bounds.SW.Lng := SWLng;
  Result.Bounds.NE.Lat := NELat;
  Result.Bounds.NE.Lng := NELng;
end;
```

Then I set the overlay active once added.
By the way, I was getting the same error also with the gmlib mega-demo example.
Is this workaround necessary? Was it my fault in adding new overlays?

Comment: This is a bug of GMLib. I have modify and fixed it and now you can download a new release from CSV repository from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/source/checkout). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Xavier, keep up this good job!